# How to calculate the difference in results between paired rows?

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, group-by

Let say I have the following dataframe:

```
  Sample_Type  test_result
GeneA(normal)    10
 GeneA(tumor)     5
GeneB(normal)     2
 GeneB(tumor)    -6
```

How can I calculate the difference between the `test_result` values for the identical genes under `Sample_Type`?

The desired output is:

```
              Sample_Type  diff_value
GeneA(normal)-GeneA(tumor)          5
GeneB(normal)-GeneB(tumor)         10
```

Any idea how to solve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `groupby` and `extract`:

```
df.groupby(df.Sample_Type.str.extract('(\w+{5})', expand=False))['test_result'].apply(lambda x: x.iloc[0]-x.iloc[1])
```

Output:

```
Sample_Type
GeneA    5
GeneB    8
Name: test_result, dtype: int64
```

Comment: @MEhsan You're welcome.  I appreciate the edit to fix the solution.